# Sort files according to their extensions

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, filenames

I have made a script that will sort files according to their extension and place them in the proper folder. For example, place `abc.jpg` in the directory `jpg`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#this script sorts files according to their extensions
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
(find . -type f) > /tmp/temp
for var in `cat /tmp/temp`
do
name=`basename "$var"`
ext=`echo $name | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2- | cut -d'.' -f2-`
mkdir -p $ext
mv "$var" $ext/ 2> /dev/null
done
IFS=$oldIFS
```

problem with this script:

1. it involves use of IFS, it is said to avoid use of IFS, as much as possible
2. it does not sorts file without file extensions
3. it will sort files like abc.tar.bz in folder named bz, but however such a file should go in tar.bz folder
4. see line 9 of my script; if any file contain more no. of dots(in its name) than no. of `cut -d'.' -f2-` in the script than if will result in file name taken in extension part.
    for example, a file named `i.am.live.in.india.and.i.study.computer.science.txt` will be placed in folder named `study.computer.science.txt`

you may also suggest any tweaks to make this script more smaller and neat.

Comment: If `abc.tar.bz2` should go into the `tar.bz2` folder, why shouldn't  `i.am.live.in.india.and.i.study.computer.science.txt` go into a folder named `am.live.in.india.and.i.study.computer.science.txt`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18919/discussion-between-edward-torvalds-and-muru).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the general problem of identifying extensions is hard, you can clean up the script a bit:

1. Tell `find` to only consider files with an extension: `-iname '*.*'`
2. Use `awk` instead of `cut`ting yourself:
3. Use a script, and then tell `find` to exec that script.

Thus: a script called, say, `move.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
for i
do
    ext=/some/where/else/$(awk -F. '{print $NF}' <<<"$i")
    mkdir -p "$ext"
    mv "$i" "$ext"
done
```

Then run `find` thus:

```
find . -name '*.*' -type f -exec move.sh {} +
```

This has the problem that you can't rearrange within the folder, so you could use `xargs`:

```
find . -name '*.*' -type f -print0 > /tmp/temp
xargs -0 move.sh < /tmp/tmp
```

---

I'm not too sure of the efficiency involved, but another approach would be to get all the extensions, then move all the files involved in one swoop.

Something like:

```
find . -name '*.*' -type f -print0 | sed -z 's/.*\.//g' | sort -zu > /tmp/file-exts
```

This should get you a list of unique file extensions. Then our `move.sh` will look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i
do
    mkdir -p "$i"
    find . -name "*.$i" -type f -exec mv -t "$i" {} +
done
```

And we'll run it:

```
xargs -0 move.sh < /tmp/file-exts
```

---

I make quite a few assumptions in this post, such as `sed` and `sort` supporting `-z` (allowing them to work with the NUL-terminated lines that `find` and `xargs` thrive on).

Comment: @edwardtorvalds it's the path where you want the sorted files to go to. Use it if you use the first approach (`find` with `-exec`). If you want the files to go in the same directory where you ran `find`, remove it and use the second approach (`find`, followed by `xargs`).

Comment: how come the script works fine for i.am.live.in.india.and.i.study.computer.science.txt and not for abcdg.tar.bz ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I assume `abcdg.tar.bz` goes in to a folder named `bz`?

Comment: yes, but i.am.live.in.india.and.i.study.computer.science.txt goes in txt folder

Comment: oh i see you grabbing the last part :p

Comment: @edwardtorvalds as I said, determining whether an arbitrary string is an extension or not is too hard. Gilles used extra code for some known extensions. I didn't.

Comment: I have just used the second approach and it works very fast and fine, thanks

Answer (score 3):

#### Recursing into subdirectories

Parsing the output of `find` is unreliable. What if there was a file name with a newline in it? Use `find … -exec …`, which guarantees reliable processing.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '…' {} \;
```

The shell snippet `…` receives the file name in `$0`. Note that this is a separate shell process, it doesn't inherit variables or functions from the grandparent script. You can speed up processing by using the same shell subprocess to handle multiple files.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for x; do … done' _ {} +
```

This time, inside the loop, the file name is in the variable `x`.

#### Breaking up the file name

Invoking external utilities such as `sed`, `cut`, etc. is fragile: you have to be extremely careful to avoid mangling some file names. You don't need that: the shell's built-in string processing features are enough for what you want to do here. Given a file name `$x`:

```
directory=${x%/*}
basename=${x##*/}
extension=…
if [ -n "$extension" ]; then
  mkdir -p "$directory/extension"
  mv "$x" "$directory/extension"
fi
```

#### The extension

What is the extension of a file? It's the part after one of the `.` in the names. There's no standard that says which one. It's up to you to decide what you consider to be the extension in cases like `foo.tar.gz` or `bar-1.2`.

Here's some example code that considers common compression extensions to nest, and that requires extensions to contain a letter, so that `foo-1.2.tar.gz` is considered to have the extension `tar.gz`.

```
extension=
while case "${basename##*.}" in
        gz|bz2|xz) extension=.${basename##*.}$extension;; # stackable extension
        *) false;;
do
  basename=${basename%.*}
done
case "${basename##*.}" in
  "$basename") :;; # no . ==> no extension
  *[!0-9A-Za-z]*) :;; # only allow alphanumeric characters
  *[A-Za-z]*) extension=${basename##*.}$extension;; # non-stackable extension
  *) false;; # require at least one letter
esac
extension=${extension#.}
```